# Haskell: preventing data modification

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have the following code which does the job of changing the configuration file:

```
mutateConfig :: (Config -> Config) -> IO ()
mutateConfig f = do
    !cfg <- readConfig
    let !newCfg = f cfg
     in writeConfig newCfg
```

Bang patterns are used to disable lazy evaluation: i need writeConfig to be called **after** an old configuration was parsed and modified with function `f`.

But there is still a problem: imagine that `f` gives an error. In this case writeConfig has already opened the file for writing (because it is called first by lazy evaluation) when an error occures, so the configuration file gets lost.

I have tried to compose a simple step-by-step logic from IO monads (in order to prevent the loss of data) like this

```
!cfg <- readConfig
newCfg <- return $ f cfg
writeConfig newCfg
```

but this doesn't work either (I kind of expected that).

What would be the correct way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Laziness doesn't explain any problems you may be having, unless readConfig uses lazy IO.  If it does, I'd argue that's a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: @Carl `readConfig` uses the `readFile` function, which is (I believe) lazy. So yes, you are right! Which function should I use to read configurations strictly?

Comment: Are you sure `Config` is fully strict? If it was any errors in `f` would be caught before attempting to write the file because of the bang pattern on `newCfg`, even if the file was read lazily (I just tested this). You should still make sure the file is read strictly because it could cause problems when trying to write back to the config file. You can do this with the [`strict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-0.3.2/docs/System-IO-Strict.html) package. (but melphomene's temporary and rename is probably a better solution)

Comment: @cchalmers I missed a bang pattern in one of the fields of `Config`. I've just fixed this and `mutateConfig` is working just I expect it to. Thank you very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Config` is completely strict (no embedded bottoms within), you can do this:

```
do
    cfg <- readConfig
    let newCfg = f cfg
    evaluate newCfg
    writeConfig newCfg
```

If it's not, you could do something like `evaluate (`[`deepseq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.1.1/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:deepseq)`newCfg ())`.

But there's another problem: In general, writing a file can fail due to I/O errors (for example because the disk is full). To avoid this, you can write to a temporary file and [rename](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.3.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:renameFile) it to the real target at the end. Doing it this way guarantees you only overwrite the config if there were no errors during the writing.

Comment: Hi! This still doesn't work! Btw I don't need `deepseq` here since `Config` is indeed strict.

Comment: What do you mean by "this" and what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: This - what you suggested. Doesn't work - still changes the file (and I am left with an empty file after the error is displayed).

Comment: Anyways, I just found out that `Config` was not completely strict (due to a bug). See my comment above. Thanks!

Comment: I suggested two different things (three if you count deepseq).

Comment: I'm saying it's still not clear which of my 2 (or 3) suggestions you tried and I've been trying to find out and you've been avoiding giving out any information.

Comment: a better way to write `evaluate (deepseq newCfg ())` is `evaluate (force newCfg)`